# Why is Rc<RefCell<T>> much more common than Rc<Cell<T>>?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, interior-mutability

Lots of resources online mention how Rc<RefCell> can be used to combine multiple ownership with interior mutability. This left me wondering: why is RefCell the go-to here, rather than Cell? I'm assuming this has practical limitations, but from a purely technical perspective it can be done, e.g.:

```
let cell = Cell::new(5);
let rc1 = Rc::new(cell);
let rc2 = rc1.clone();
rc1.set(7);
rc2.set(9);
```

I imagine Cell, with its more numerous restrictions, makes it less suitable for practical applications. E.g. calling any &mut self method on the contained value. This seems particularly tricky to deal with if the contained value does not implement Copy. But this is conjecture on my part. Is there a clear reasoning for this?

Comment: Why would people recommend something "less suitable for practical applications" and "tricky to deal with"? Especially if its a broad, non-specific suggestion as would be given to most newcomers.

Comment: Basically, the answer to this question is the same as: "why are there different kind of `Cell`s in Rust ([`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), [`LazyCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.LazyCell.html), [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html), [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html), ...)?" The answer is: each of these is a safe wrapper on `UnsafeCell`, each made for a given purpose. `RefCell` happens to be the one that fits.

Comment: Another aspect is probably that people use what they are most comfortable with. The Rust book talks about RefCell a lot more, probably because it's the most flexible. Therefore, more people probably know about RefCell than Cell, and if RefCell _works_ (even if Cell would be better), why would you spend time looking for something else?

Comment: `Cell` is like a mutable `T` that you don't declare `mut`, whereas `RefCell` is like a mutable `&T` that you don't declare `&mut`. And `Rc` is for shared ownership. The nature of sharing is that you do so with references, not with values. (Indeed, Rust makes sharing values *impossible* unless behind an `Rc` or similar struct.)